# Configure Kubernetes logs in different path with Spring Logback

Tags: spring, logging, kubernetes, logback, fluentd

I've a application Java/Spring boot that is running in a Kubernetes pod, the logs is configure to stdout, fluentd get logs from default path:

```
<source>
 @type tail
 path /var/log/containers/*.log
 pos_file /pos/containers.pos
 time_key time
 time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
 tag kubernetes.*
 format json
 read_from_head true
</source>
```

In my logback xml configs i've a appender json file:

```
<appender name="jsonAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/spring-boot-logger.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}.%i</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <KeyValuePair key="service" value="java-app" />
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>1MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>
```

How do I integrate this separate log file other than stdout in my Kubernete settings along with Fluentd, to send my json logs in a different path

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. move that file onto an emptyDir volume (or hostPath I guess but use emptyDir) and then
2. run fluentd/bit as a sidecar which reads from that volume and
3. forwards to the rest of your fluentd setup.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the dockerfile for the spring boot app create a directory where logs will be written
2. In the logback xml file have a FileAppender which will write logs in that directory path
3. Have the logback xml file as part of the jar file in `resources` folder.
4. Add Fluentd sidecar into the pod spec of the spring boot app
5. Configure Fluentd sidecar to tail logs from the log file written in that directory path.